# MediaPlayer comsume the RAM even though the Task has finished C#

Tags: c#, wpf, task, windows-media-player

I'm triying to make a multi-thead Player to play muiltiples sounds effects (mouse hover, click, animations, ...). The sound is working properly but I realise that the RAM was getting fuller every time the sound play. So I desided to set a delegate on `audio.BufferingEnded` closing the file, but that didn't chage anything.

**Mi code.**

```
Task.Run(() => {

    try
    {
        var audio = new MediaPlayer { Volume = DataHandler.SoundVolume };
        audio.Open(new Uri(GetFullPath(fileName)));
        audio.BufferingEnded += delegate { audio.Close(); };
        audio.Play();   
    }
    catch (Exception) { throw; }

}).ContinueWith(async (t) => {

    Console.WriteLine("has finished...");

});
```

Is there a way to Dispose the MediaPlayer when reproduction has finished?. 
If some one can help me it would be geat.

Comment: "*but I realise that the RAM was getting fuller every*" this is what .net does, if you think you have a memory leak you **need** to use a profiler (not task manager) , "*Then I decided to show a message*" a break point is more reliable who knows what sync context you are on. "*I think that the problem is that the task never ends*" you need to do your own due diligence with this and prove it beyond all reasonable doubt, not guess

Comment: -" I decided to show a message"- was to see if the task got completed.

Comment: ok I'm going to reformulate the question to the RAM problem.

Comment: event delegate is preventing player from being garbage collected which causes memory leak. Also you should not open for each request. open once and reuse the same player for the lifetime of the form/window.

Comment: I also believe you are subscribing to that event after the player has already played so there is nothing to buffer

Comment: The thing is that I need a  multi-thead player for multiples sound effects. But I need to release the memori space after finishing.

Comment: I coment the delegate line and the RAM do not get free.